# Method Reference in enum with Generics

Tags: java

I'm trying to get rid of a ton of redundant code someone wrote (60 lines of calling the same function where just a few parameters are different, and this happens in 4 different places in the same file).

I have a function like this:

```
public <E, T, G extends SomeClass> void sendChanges(String personName,
                                                    List<MyObject> message,
                                                    String tableName,
                                                    Function<List<E>, Tuple2<List<T>,Integer>> converter,
                                                    Function<Integer, List<G>> fetcher,
                                                    int stuff,
                                                    String className,
                                                    BaseDAO dao,
                                                    Class<T> classType,
                                                    ProxyObject proxyInfo);
```

You can see that it has two method references in it its parameters.

I'm trying to create an enum whose values I can then iterate over in a loop (instead of 60 nearly-identical typed-out function calls). I thought I needed to put method references where you see `tableName` and `className` below, but putting the letters like they appear in the method definition doesn't work, nor does putting `<E, T>` after `private final` doesn't work, as it complains about invalid start of expression.

```
public static enum TableNamesTest {
    SOME_THING_1("some_thing_1", "SomeThing1Class");

    private final String tableName;
    private final String className;

    private <E, T, G extends ChangeTable> TableNamesTest(String tableName, String className,
            Function<List<E>, Tuple2<List<T>, Integer>> modelConvertFunction,
            Function<Integer, List<G>> fetchChanges,
            Class<T> classType) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
        this.className = className;
    }

    public String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }
};
```

How can I put a method reference in the enum's variables declaration area so that the enum works the way I want it to? This is Java 8.

Comment: `Function` is not a method reference, per se, its just a functional programming helper interface added in Java 8 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html). why not just have a list of `Function` instances to iterate though? Why do they need to be in an enum?